# react native stuck in configuring react-native-gesture-handler

Tags: android, node.js, reactjs, react-native

I did this:

1. `react-native init "project name"`
2. `npm install react-navigation`
3. `npm link`
4. `react-native run-android`

and boom !!!! it's stuck and did not run just like this :

[image: See the PowerShell image]

Please help me in this case ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you haven't installed Android SDK platform 25. I had the same issue and solved using below method.

1. Open Android Studio
2. Open SDK Manager
3. Click SDK Platforms Tab
4. Select android 7.1.1
           (Nougat) API level is 25
5. Apply

After installing that press OK and try again to build the project.

Comment: Should i do this for each dependency which i want to add to my project ?